# Meteor login system account creation "invalid email"

Tags: meteor

I'm using accounts-password and accounts-ui. I came back to my project after a few days, and now when I try to create a new user it says "invalid email". I've tried resetting the project, rebooting the vm, etc. No errors, just won't create accounts anymore.

I created a new dummy project, and account creation works fine there.

I tried implementing the validateNewUser callback, but it's never called, and my browser isn't even making an ajax request when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, this answer isn't likely to help anyone else, but here goes.

The problem was caused because I had included loginButtons twice. Both forms were rendered exactly on top of each other, and both responded to every event. I'm not sure exactly what conflicted about them, but removing one fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I did exactly the same thing - one login button in my nav bar and the other on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor doesn't use ajax for its calls, you would have to look at your web socket frames for any communication.

Its somewhat likely your `validateNewUser` is causing this. It must return true for the user to be created. Try removing it and see if it helps.

Its hard to really say beyond this using the info you've given. If you have any other packages in your project they may also cause it.